# Saving multiple object reference using this in java

Tags: java, object

I have following Building class:

```
public class Building {

static ArrayList<Floor> floors = new ArrayList<Floor>();
public Elevator elevator;
public static int floorNo;

//constructor creates elevator and floor objects
public Building() {
    elevator = new Elevator(Elevator.building);

    int count = 1;
    while (count != FLOORS+1) {
        floors.add(new Floor(Elevator.building, count));
        count++;
    }
}

//returns proper floor object by accessing the array
public static Floor floor(int floorNumber) {
    this.floorNo = floorNumber;
    return floors.get(floorNumber-1);
}

public static int getFloorNo() {
    return floorNo;
}

}
```

If I create following objects and call some method on them. I lose the identity of the objects and when I am calling the method, I am don't know which object it is being called upon.

```
//I save the 1 using this in floor(), so floorNo = 1
Floor firstFloor = building.floor(1);   

//now floorNo = 2
Floor secondFloor = building.floor(2); 

//here how do I know that firstFloor is 1 since floorNo value is changed
firstFloor.waitForElevator();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `static` members as little as possible. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) and follow OOP practices.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you created your `firstFloor` using a constructor that takes its **floor number** (the second argument).

I guess that your `Floor` class looks like this:

```
public class Floor {
   private final int floorNo;
   private final Elevator elevator;

   public Floor(final Elevator elevator, final int floorNo) {
       this.elevator = elevator;
       this.floorNo = floorNo;
   }
}
```

To get the `floorNo` of your `firstFloor`, which is just an instance of `Floor`, you should create (and use!) a **getter** for its `floorNo` field.

For example, you could add to your `Floor` class the following method:

```
public int getFloorNo() {
    return this.floorNo;
)
```

Thus, you could know the *floor number* of any instance of `Floor` like this:

```
System.out.println(firstFloor.getFloorNo());
```

Would output:

```
1
```

Comment: firstFloor is created by a test method, I don't know the variable test method. That is what I am asking, how do I save the object name 'firstFloor'. thanks

Comment: @user2916628... I'm sorry, but I really can't understand what you're asking. If English is not your native language, try  just adding some examples of what you want to have in your question, I guess that this would give you some much more accurate answers :)

Comment: I am saying the objects firstFloor and secondFloor are being created in junit test so you can't really use those names as you did in your example. When you say 'System.out.println(firstFloor.getFloorNo());,' you are using the object name (firstFloor).